# Check the node is present or not in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xslt, Though I manage to work on it. But I struck with one case for which I need a help from expert. I am trying to finding the node which is Exists or not. I already search this same question, in which I didn't get the expected answer. I am having a node, MainNode->SubNode1->SubNode2->SunNode3. If I am checking like below

```
<xsl:if test= "not(//MainNode/SubNode1/SubNode2/SunNode3)">
```

Which is working, but if same I converts in to Variable, as below

```
<xsl:if test= "not(//MainNode/$Var1/$Var2/SunNode3)">
```

where, Var1 = SubNode1, Var2 = SubNode2

Why it is not working. I can't use Variable in path searching. If not what is the solution for this.

Comment: The context of your question is not quite clear, especially the part of how - and **why** -  you define the variable. In general, if the variables in question are *strings*, you need a processor that can dynamically evaluate a string as a path (i.e. either supports XSLT 3.0 or provides an extension). Alternatively, you could rewrite the expression, using the (awkward and inefficient) form of `*[name()=$Var1]` instead of `$Var1` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't construct path step dynamically using variables. But you can use variable to filter element by name, for example :

```
<xsl:if test= "not(//MainNode/*[name()=$Var1]/*[name()=$Var2]/SunNode3)">
```

Comment: More generally, *XPath is not a macro language*. Variables contain values, not fragments of expression text.